# If condition not working in email template in magento2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I need to use an if conditions on an email template, but somehow it is not working, I have tried many approaches but in vain. The approach of islogin variable is I have created one hidden text field which have name and id set
to islogin. Below is my code what's wrong with this code.

```
<input name="islogin" id="islogin" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text hide" type="hidden" />
<table class="message-details">
    {{if !data.islogin}}
    <tr>
        <td><b>{{trans "Name"}}</b></td>
        <td>{{var data.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/if}}
    {{if !data.islogin || data.islogin}}
    <tr>
        <td><b>{{trans "Email"}}</b></td>
        <td>{{var data.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/if}}
</table>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: it displays empty table. even though if I try to print {{var data.islogin}} I can see the result but not in case of an if conditions

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering the email template. Here you have no access to the input variables of the html. The if statements can evaluate only variables from your server, system variables or custom variables.

```
<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>
```

This is PHP. As i know, you can not use it in the email template.

Comment: is there any solution for this? because I need to render the template according to the user login condition. As we can see the data of an email and name if I remove the if condition, I thought we can access that in an if condition

Comment: Perhaps you will find an idea here: http://www.srikanth.me/magento-customizing-email-templates/